# Convert a linked list

Tags: c#, algorithm

Here is the question.

> Given a linked list like a1-a2-a3-a4-b1-b2-b3-b4. Convert it into a1-b1-a2-b2-a3-b3-a4-b4.

My algorithm is sort of inefficient.

1. Clone the linked list twice, the result will be "lista" and "listb".
2. Remove half of them then make lista = a1-a2-a3-a4 and listb = b1-b2-b3-b4;
3. Try to combine lista and listb in a certain way.(I have no clue though).

Need your thought.

Comment: How do you define the sort order? Is it by the number that is tied to the linked list? Could you elaborate your data structure for the linked list?

Comment: If your question is specifically about C#, you should say so.  If you can't use pointers, how do you know it is a linked list?

Comment: It is an Amazon interview question. It is just asked. It is a linked list, no doubt. Why down vote?

Comment: The question is about a linked list, yet you explicitly reject ANY answers that have to do with linked lists (as opposed to more generic queues), suggesting the question is, at best, badly worded, but nonetheless misleading.

Comment: @Scott, thanks for comment. I guess that we were talking different things. The pointer I referred to was the pointer in C++ language. Because I thought the other solutions used C++, they mentioned using pointer.-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can go through the linked list, if the item starts with "a", add them to a queue "A", if it's "b", add them to queue "B", and then dequeue A and B in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily enough with the C# `LinkedList` class.

Start by scanning the list to find the `b1` node. You have another variable that starts at `list.First`. Then you move the `b1` node to be after the first node, move to `b2`, move the other variable to `a2`, and repeat until you get to the end of the list.

It looks something like this:

```
var aNode = list.First();
var bNode = list.First();
// scan the list looking for the first `b` node.
while (!(bNode.Value[0] == 'b'))
    bNode = bNode.Next;

// now interleave the elements
while (bNode != null)
{
    var nextB = bNode.Next;
    var nextA = aNode.Next;
    list.Remove(bNode);
    list.AddAfter(aNode, bNode);
    aNode = nextA;
    bNode = nextB;
}
```

The above will work if there are at least as many `a` nodes as `b` nodes. If there can be more 'b' nodes than 'a' nodes, then you'll have to check the `aNode` value after every iteration to ensure that you haven't gone too far. That's easily done with:

```
while (bNode != null && aNode.Value[0] == 'a')
```

Answer (score 1):

The details will depend on how the lists are implemented, but here's one idea:

Have one pointer, ap, start at the beginning of the original list; get a second, bp, to point to the first b node.

Now, repeatedly move the item pointed to by bp to be just after ap, and advance ap to the next a & bp to the next b.

Since each pointer traverses the list at most once, the whole algorithm is linear.

Answer (score 1):

Have two pointers, first pointing at the beginning, e.g., `a`, second pointing in the middle (where b sequence starts), e.g., `b` and then, in the loop with some stop condition:

```
aNext = a.next
bNext = b.next
a.next = b
b.next = aNext
a = aNext
b = bNext
```

Comment: I use C#, no pointers there. I guess that you want to use C++.

Comment: Sorry, didn't have much to do with C#. Maybe you should add C# tag to your question? But from [LinkedList documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx), it seems to me it should be possible to come up with similar algorithm using `GetEnumarator()` (and its `MoveNext()`), `Remove(LinkedListNode<T>)` and `AddAfter(LinkedListNode<T>, LinkedListNode<T>)`.

Answer (score 1):

Tested the below code and it works perfectly -

```
    public void arrangeInPairs()
    {
        if(head == null)
            return;

        Node slow = head;
        Node fast = head;

        while(fast != null)
        {           
            slow = slow.next;
            fast = fast.next.next;
        }//now slow is at the start of 2nd sequence (b1) and fast is null

        //move back fast to the beginning
        fast = head;

        while(slow.next != null)
        {
            Node sTemp = slow.next;
            Node fTemp = fast.next;

            fast.next = slow;
            slow.next = fTemp;
            fast = fTemp;
            slow = sTemp;
        }
        fast.next = slow; //if you skip this then a4 will be still pointing to b1 causing a cyclic loop
        slow.next = null;// last element would be slow (b4) so assign its next to  null

        printList(); //a1 b1 a2 b2 a3 b3 a4 b4
    }
```

Comment: Consider explaining what your algorithm does

Comment: This is called as runner technique where you make use of 2 ptrs. 'fast' moves every two elements for every one move s'low' makes. So by the time fast reaches null (end), slow pointer would be at middle (b1).
At this point move back the fast pointer to the beginning (head). In the second while loop for each iteration select element starting from slow and insert it after fast
At the end of this while loop slow pointer would be at the end 'b4' and hence you assign it to null, but fast would be at a4 and still would be connecting to b1 (a4's next is b1 - original sequence) hence assign it to slow.

Comment: And the algorithm takes o(n) linear time

Comment: Thank-you Vamsi for a fine description and actual code sample. Wish I could give you more points :)

Answer (score 0):

1. First swap elements in the middle pair
2. Next swap elements in the middle two pairs
3. Next swap elements in the middle three pairs
4. iterate n-1 steps.

   Ex: with n = 4.
      a1 a2 a3 a4 b1 b2 b3 b4 
      a1 a2 a3 b1 a4 b2 b3 b4 
      a1 a2 b1 a3 b2 a4 b3 b4 
      a1 b1 a2 b2 a3 b3 a4 b4
      Time Complexity : O(n)
      Space Complexity: O(1)